# Examples of VB.NET lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq

Where can I find complex LINQ examples made using VB.NET Lambda Expression syntax?

During my searches I always found [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088) but they use the other notation and for me is not always clear how to transform that code into a lambda expression.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could just look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx). They have at least one example for each of the IEnumerable-extensions in C# and also in VB.Net.

Some random examples:

```
' Select
Dim squares As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = _
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(x) x * x)

' Aggregate
Dim reversed As String = _
        words.Aggregate(Function(ByVal current, ByVal word) word & " " & current)

' Max
Dim max As Integer = pets.Max(Function(pet) _
                                      pet.Age + pet.Name.Length)

 ' SkipWhile
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = _
        amounts.SkipWhile(Function(amount, index) _
                              amount > index * 1000)
```