# Expression expected using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to remove the lines from a text file that contains a specific word using vb.net. I have this done using c#

**c#**

```cs
var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TemporaryLBL);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("$PhysicsNo#"));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(TemporaryLBL, newLines);
```

**vb.net**

```vb
Dim oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TemporaryLBL)
Dim newLines = oldLines.Where(Function(line) Return Not line.Contains("$PhysicsNo#") End Function)
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(TemporaryLBL, newLines)
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, so far I'm getting an error on the Function part: `Expression expected.`

Comment: `Function(line) Not line.Contains("$PhysicsNo#"))` should do it.

Comment: In case you're not aware of it: http://converter.telerik.com/ - using that confirms @Saragis's comment, which ought to be the answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of VB.NET lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884011/examples-of-vb-net-lambda-expression)

Comment: You're trying to define a function in place of a lambda expression.  You'll need to review what the lambda syntax looks like.

Comment: @Saragis the error is still there

Comment: You need to remove `End Function` as well, as I did

Comment: I used this sample from: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), but same error. weird :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(TemporaryLBL, IO.File.ReadAllLines(TemporaryLBL).Where(Function(line) Not line.Contains("$PhysicsNo#")))
```

you could also try:

```
Dim oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TemporaryLBL)
Dim newLines = From line In oldLines Where (Not line.Contains("$PhysicsNo#"))
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(TemporaryLBL, newLines)
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked for me. Is it run-time error or compile error?

Comment: Compile error: Expression expected. In fact when typing the word Fuction appears underline with the before error

Comment: is it Windows or Webb application? Can you post your exact code? All of it. I tried using the line above and it worked in windows app. without importing any libraries

Comment: check my update. it does not use the word function but produces the same output